# Understanding the Rieman Surface of the Complex Logarithm

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces

I was reading Complex Logarithm from Wikipedia. I got stuck on a line. I am quoting "Another way to resolve the indeterminacy is to view the logarithm as a function whose domain is not a region in the complex plane, but a Riemann surface that covers the punctured complex plane in an infinite-to-1 way". I understood everything before this line.

I could not understand this picture as well.

[image]
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm--is the link.

Can anyone make me understand by giving simple example? I really can not make progress on it.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: As a function $f : \Bbb C^* \to \Bbb C$ the log is not well defined. However, as a function $f : X \to \Bbb C$ the function is well defined, where $X$ is the Riemann surface associated to $\rm{log}$.

Comment: also $X$ is just the graph of the exponential function ($\{(x,y) \mid y = \exp(x) \}$) except that you look at it the other way.

Comment: Can u please elaborate? How the picture is representing the domain?@NicolasHemelsoet

Comment: Can u please elaborate? How the picture is representing the domain?@mercio